# Making `volume` in docker-compose.yml work earlier than dockerfile

Tags: docker

my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  admin_site:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.local
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "8010:8010"
    restart: always
```

I want to mount current folder to `/usr/src/app`

`Dockerfile.local`

```
FROM python:3.9.5
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y netcat
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN pip install pipenv
RUN pipenv install --dev --system
```

When I try to `docker compose -f docker-compose.yml build`

This error occurs.

`ERROR:: --system is intended to be used for pre-existing Pipfile installation, not installation of specific packages. Aborting.`

I guess it means there is no `Pipfile`

However There is `Pipfile` in my current directly.

So I guess `volumes:` doesn't work before Dockerfile?

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: [`COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) the files you need for your image to build

Comment: I'd recommend deleting that `volumes:` block entirely; all of your application's code should be built into the image.  A Python virtual environment might be a better match if you're looking for a lightly isolated Python installation that can work directly on your local code.

Answer (score 0):

Mounts always apply to Container and not to the Image Build.
So would use

```
# DO
# $ pipenv lock --dev --requirements > requirements.txt
# before build!
COPY requirements*.txt ./
RUN python -m pip --no-cache-dir install -r requirements.txt
```

This is not using your Pipenv-File, you have to manually generate the requirements-file. There are some benefits doing it like that:

- Packages in Docker-Image can't be changed by accident
- You can define versions for dependencies separately, very helpful if you have bugs in dependency-packages, but need to update the main package
- Pipenv does not run lock on image build (takes ages every time)

Furthermore copying whole folder forces docker build to not reuse this layer on any file change.